# QueryOver – ensure adding a join table only once

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a fairly complex use case that requires performing the same SQL tasks conditionally in various parts of the code. I wanted to duplicate as little code as possible, so I built a few static helper methods that allow me to add some JOIN statements when needed.

I know this probably could've been done a bit more cleanly with extensions, but for now my code looks something like this:

```
static class Foo
{
    // Actually adds some filters which need additional JOINs
    public static IQueryOver<Transaction, Transaction> FromRetailer(Retailer retailer, IQueryOver<Transaction, Transaction> baseQuery = null)
    {
        RetailLocation retailLocation = null;

        return ForRetailerBase(baseQuery)
            .Where(t => retailLocation.Retailer == retailer);
    }

    // Auxiliary method which only adds some JOINs needed in various places
    public static IQueryOver<Transaction, Transaction> ForRetailerBase(IQueryOver<Transaction, Transaction> baseQuery = null)
    {
        if (baseQuery == null)
            baseQuery = QueryOver(); // Custom method that creates a vanilla IQueryOver instance

        // Add all sorts of JOINs needed to query the retailer
        return baseQuery
            .JoinAlias(...)
            .Left.JoinAlias(...)
            // and so on
        ;
    }
}
```

In the business logic, I either need to actually filter by retailer (in which case I call `FromRetailer()`, which calls `ForRetailerBase()` for me), or I don't need to filter by retailer – but I still need the JOINs added by `ForRetailerBase()` later on for grouping. Calling `ForRetailerBase()` unconditionally obviously breaks things when `FromRetailer()` is also called.

I'm currently solving this in a very clumsy fashion, by using a boolean in the business logic in order to execute `ForRetailerBase()` conditionally, only if `FromRetailer()` isn't executed.

I realize this could be fixed on two levels: either use a more adequate pattern altogether, or add those JOINs conditionally in `ForRetailerBase()`, by interrogating the `baseQuery` object to determine whether it already has the necessary JOINs. I'd rather go with the first approach, if one is available (this part of the code is still relatively young, and I can easily refactor it) – but I'll settle for the second approach as well. Problem is, I don't know how to advance in either direction.

I also realize the superficial solution is to remove the call to `ForRetailerBase()` from method `FromRetailer()`, and calling it unconditionally from the business logic, but that's just as bad as my current solution, because it requires my business logic to know how those methods work internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ForRetailerBase`, `FromRetailer` looks to me as something the business logic should not know at all. It looks like query helpers, which should be handled by a query repository.

Such repository will expose querying methods for the business, methods which would internally call your `ForRetailerBase` or `FromRetailer` as required.

This way, your business will not need knowledge of how to build your queries, and your querying logic will still be factorized, inside the repository.

Side note: your question does not really look bound to the specific technologies you are using. It looks to me more as a code design question. Maybe should you ask it on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ instead, which is meant for such questions (see its [on topic page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).